# Floating rate bond valuation and Duration

Tags: bond, valuation, duration, floating-rate

I would like to know how a floating rate bond will be valued when LIBOR is used to compute the coupon cashflows and the bond is discounted using an OIS rate. Normally I have seen valuation of a FRB when both the coupon and discount curves are the same. What happens when these are different? Also, what happened would be the duration of such a bond ?

Comment: "Normally" the swap curve was used to discount cash flows a long time ago. You need to read more recent materials. Also "duration" is not a convenient way to look at the interest rate risk of anything.

Comment: USD Libor will cease to get published in June 2023.  What happens to the bond coupons ? This is relevant.